# react-jss displayName being overwritten by injectSheets

Tags: reactjs, jss

I have a functional component Foo that I am injecting a stylesheet into using react-jss.

I manually set a displayName of Foo to be "Foo" but I noticed that after calling injectSheet on Foo the displayName changed to "JssContextSubscriber". Why is this happening? And are there any issues if I change it back to "Foo"?

I read that displayNames are only for debugging purposes but the issue is that I am using another library called jsxToString which when it converts  to a string actually reads the displayName and writes  instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to whatever you want, but if you want your name to stick you'll want to set the component name *after* you pass it to `injectSheet`. Note that recent versions of `react-jss` (10.0.1+ I think) will append the original display name which might already suit your needs.